# C# Windows Forms - new class that inherits from PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms

The problem is as follows: I try to write my first app based on Windows Forms, where some calculations will be done.

In form I have defined a picture box (name = `canva`) that is supposed to sketch cross sections of the steel profiles that are to be analyzed.

I do not want to have all the methods that will draw something on this picture box in the `MainForm.cs`, thus I created new class called `Sketch` that inherits from `PictureBox`.

The new class definition is thus quite simple for a while:

```
public class Sketch:PictureBox
{

}
```

So when I initilalize the form, I re-define the `canva` to be of the new type of `Sketch`, to access later new methods that will draw certain things, arrows, etc.

```
        Sketch canva = new Sketch();
        canva.Show.
        canva.BackColor = Color.Red;
        MessageBox.Show("SketchboxName: " + canva.Name.ToString());
```

But then the `canva` does not show, and I do not even can check the name of this control through `MessageBox`.

Shouldn't such a new class definition inherit all the methods from `pictureBox`?

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Where are you calling this from?  If it is in the Form constructor, then it won't show because the form is not yet created. You need to call it from another event, such as From Load.

Comment: Is this `canva` added to the form, like this `this.Controls.Add(canva)`. This code is automatically generated when you drag and drop controls.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith, you can actually do it in the constructor, but after the call to `InitializeComponent()`. The method `InitializeComponent` does initialize the form and create the controls.

Comment: `canva.Show.` is not real code. Please post real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile your project after having added the new class `Sketch`. Since `Sketch` is a control, it now appears in the Toolbox window of the forms designer. You can simply drag and drop it to the design surface as any other control to add it to your form.

Alternatively, if you already have a `PictureBox` on your form, you can open the file `MyForm.designer.cs` (where `MyForm` is the name of your form). You will see a variable `PictureBox canva;`. Change its type to `Sketch canva;`. There is also a `this.canva = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()` somewhere. Change it to `this.canva = new Skecth()`. This will convert the existing `PictureBox` to a `Sketch`.

Note that your `Sketch canva = new Sketch();` does not work, because it defines only a local variable `canva` instead of assigning a `Sketch` to the existing field `this.canva`. Also, you would have to remove the existing PictureBox from and add your new control to the Form's `Controls` collection to make it visible and functional. But prefer one of the two approaches I described above, the first one being the most simple and safe one.

Comment: Year, I am very beginner in coding, and probably have bad habits from waiting macros in VBA Excel. Year, first solution seems to be an answer to the problem. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal working example of adding an inherited `PictureBox` to a `Form`.

```
void Main()
{
    Form form = new Form();
    Sketch canva = new Sketch();
    canva.BackColor = Color.Red;
    form.Controls.Add(canva);
    form.Show();
}

public class Sketch : PictureBox { }
```

That gives me:

[image: form]

Hopefully this gives you enough information to hunt down how the designer is doing it.